# Where does android set padding for nine-patch image?

Tags: android, android-framework

As you know, nine-patch image contain the information that how the content aligned. So how does android get the padding of the content. I just can't find the corresponding code in framework.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

The left and top guidelines tell the framework what can be stretched, the right and bottom guidelines tell it which rows and columns are padding (actually, the area where the inner content can go).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already know how nine-patch image works. But i just want to find where does this function implements. Something like set padding and so on. Because i am want to modify android framework recently.

Comment: @user674199 i don't think theres anything in the sdk that's gonna give you what you're looking for. it's likely some native function that knows how to process draw 9's